# Ruby/Rails - Insert Parameters Into Query String Located In the Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, query-string

I have a link_to in my view which is going to a URL( query string) that is created dynamically in the controller.

```
<%= link_to "Search Venue", @venue_search, :target => :blank %>
```

and in the controller I'm pulling some attributes from a model and using those values in a query to hit Yahoo's API and

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
search_values = {
    :api_key => 'xxxxxxxxx',
    :search_text => @event.venue_name,
    :location => @event.venue_zipcode,
    :radius => 100
}
@venue_search = "http://yahooapis.com/rest/?method=venue.search&" + search_values.to_query
```

And everything is working perfect so far.

I would like to manually enter a few more parameters into the query and I'm just wondering what would be the best direction to go.

Is there a way to create a form which some text fields that I can use to insert parameters manually into the query string and to use the submit button to call the url as a link_to?

I was thinking something like

```
<% form_for @venue_search(:city, :state) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :city %>
  <%= f.text_field :state %>
<% end %>
```

And some how add those two new parameters to the query and then execute the query

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If i properly understand your question, you can use for sending 'GET' request - in such case parameters will be placed in query:

```
<% form_for @venue_search, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :city %>
  <%= f.text_field :state %>
<% end %>
```

Hope its help you.